# Load tomcat application via DNS without typing 8080

Tags: apache, tomcat, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, tomcat7

I am having a Amazon EC2 Ubuntu instance. I have installed LAMP server and tomcat 7. I also have application running in tomcat.

Now, my URL for apache is - http://ec2-54-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/

My URL for tomcat application is: http://ec2-54-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080

Instead of writing the 8080 part, I would like to call this directly via the URL  http://ec2-54-xx-xx-xx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/.

I went through lot of tutorials, all are invalid, out dated or missing details. I am apache2, so the files inside the `apache2` directory are below.

[image]

How can I do this "properly"? Because I will purchase a domain name in this weekend and I will replace the long amazon URL with this one soon as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). You should setup nginx or httpd server instance, which would proxy requests from port 80 (http) to your local 8080 port (tomcat).

Here's a sample configuration for nginx:

```
upstream tomcat {
  server 127.0.0.1:8080; # your tomcat app address
}

server {
  listen 80;

  root /path/to/your/app/directory;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name your.app.domain;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @tomcat;
  }

  location @tomcat {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    proxy_pass http://tomcat;
  }
```

}

Comment: I know. Problem is I don't know how to.

Comment: Added sample nginx configuration.

Comment: OK but which file is this? to where should I add this code?

Comment: You can add this to `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or you can create a new file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` and then symlink it to a `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`.